# $scope value not able to read in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-rootscope

I am not sure what is wrong with this but somehow not able to read correct value of $scope.

Here is my code at controller -->

```
$scope.verifyMobile = SearchFactory.verify.query({uuid: uuid});
```

The JSON returned by rest service is -->

```
 verifyNumber -- > {"id":1,"uuid":"2222","phoneNumber":"782941768355"}
```

I convert the POJO to JSON using gson.toString(verifyNumber Java class);

But when I try to check the value of phonenumber after making service call at controller, it always comes as undefined. can anybody please help. when I hardcode the value to returned JSON, it works fine but not with service.

```
 alert(JSON.stringify($scope.verifyMobile).uuid);
```

Comment: there isn't enough detail here to reproduce your issue.  In your question, you say that you "check the value of `phonenumber`", but, #1 it's `phoneNumber`, and #2, your alert is printing `uuid`, not `phonenumber`.

Comment: @Claies - you can use phoneNumber istead of uuid. anything comes solves my issue. 2 hours I spent and cant :(

Comment: but what exactly are you asking here? you say that it works when you hardcode it but not when you make a service call, but you didn't list the code for that service.

Comment: verify: $resource('http://localhost:8084/laundry/verify/:uuid', {}, {
    query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false, params: {uuid: '@uuid'} },
    create: {method: 'POST'}
   }),

Comment: $resource is async, you are never going to have a value immediately when using it.

Comment: what should i do so that i can access the data returned from service at controller ?

Comment: your `SearchFactory.verify.query()` call is missing the callback that should execute after the server value is returned.

Comment: you may want to spend some time studying the documentation on `$resource` and async JavaScript;  right now your `.query()` call isn't valid, and you really need to understand how async callbacks work in order to understand the correct syntax to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `$resource` correctly.  From the [Angular Documentation for `$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be invoked with the following parameters:
>
> •HTTP GET "class" actions: `Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])`
>
> •non-GET "class" actions: `Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])`
>
> •non-GET instance actions: `instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])`

`query()` is a GET "class" action, so the correct call would be:

```
SearchFactory.verify.query({uuid: uuid}, function(data){
    //do something here on successful data retrieval
    $scope.verifyMobile = data;
}, function(){ 
   //do something here on failure
});
```

It's worth noting that the original call *does* actually work, but because it is an async call, what is being returned is the promise, not the actual data.

Also worth noting, the standardized HTTP actions for `$resource` look like the following:

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

Therefore, you should consider using `get` instead of `query` when retrieving a single value, instead of modifying the `query` `isArray` property, whenever possible.

Comment: I added a bit more info on the answer in case you are interested.